Return all rows that have at least one null in one of the columns using Polars
I need all the rows that have null in one of the predefined columns.
I basically need this but i have one more requirement that I cant seem to figure out.
Not every column needs to be checked.
I have a function that returns the names of the columns that need to be checked in a list.
Assume this is my dataframe:
data = pl.from_repr("""
┌───────┬───────┬─────┬───────┐
│ a     ┆ b     ┆ c   ┆ d     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ str ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ abc   ┆ null  ┆ u   ┆ true  │
│ def   ┆ abc   ┆ v   ┆ true  │
│ ghi   ┆ def   ┆ null┆ true  │
│ jkl   ┆ uvw   ┆ x   ┆ true  │
│ mno   ┆ xyz   ┆ y   ┆ null  │
│ qrs   ┆ null  ┆ z   ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┴─────┴───────┘
""")

Doing
data.filter(polars.any_horizontal(polars.all().is_null()))
gives me all rows where any of the columns contain null.
Sometimes it's fine for column c to contain a null so let's not check it.
what I want is this:
┌───────┬───────┬─────┬───────┐
│ a     ┆ b     ┆ c   ┆ d     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ str ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ abc   ┆ null  ┆ u   ┆ true  │
│ mno   ┆ xyz   ┆ y   ┆ null  │
│ qrs   ┆ null  ┆ z   ┆ null  │
└───────┴───────┴─────┴───────┘

Row 3 is not shown even though there is a null value in column c.
columns = ["a", "b", "d"]
data.filter(polars.any_horizontal(polars.all(*columns).is_null()))

This gives me
polars.exceptions.SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected 'Boolean', got 'str'
I thought maybe the columns aren't aligned or somethig because data has more columns than what the filter uses, so i did this.
columns = ["a", "b", "d"]
# notice `.select(columns)` here
data.select(columns).filter(polars.any_horizontal(polars.all(*columns).is_null()))

But is still get the same error.
How do I get the full rows of data that contain a null in one of ["a", "b", "d"] columns

This question is similar to: Polars: Select all rows with missing values in any column. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you want exclude some columns you can use .exlude():
import polars as pl

data.filter(pl.any_horizontal(pl.exclude("c").is_null()))

┌─────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ str  ┆ str ┆ bool │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ abc ┆ null ┆ u   ┆ true │
│ mno ┆ xyz  ┆ y   ┆ null │
│ qrs ┆ null ┆ z   ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

Or you can just use column names by using .col():
import polars as pl

cols = ["a","b","d"]

data.filter(pl.any_horizontal(pl.col(cols).is_null()))

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ str  ┆ str ┆ bool │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ abc ┆ null ┆ u   ┆ true │
│ mno ┆ xyz  ┆ y   ┆ null │
│ qrs ┆ null ┆ z   ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

If you want to be really flexible, you can use selectors, for example .selectors.exclude():
import polars.selectors as cs

data.filter(pl.any_horizontal(cs.exclude("c").is_null()))

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ str  ┆ str ┆ bool │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ abc ┆ null ┆ u   ┆ true │
│ mno ┆ xyz  ┆ y   ┆ null │
│ qrs ┆ null ┆ z   ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘


What I needed was polars.col(names) and not polars.all(names).
According to the docs polars.all(names) != polars.col(names) :

This function is syntactic sugar for col(names).all()

This worked:
columns = ["a", "b", "d"]
data.filter(polars.any_horizontal(polars.col(*columns).is_null()))

